# Get attribute text instead of id in custom customer grid

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, customer-grid

I want to show a custom attribute of a customer in the adminhtml customer grid.
I managed to do this by creating a new module, and extends the `setCollection` method of `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid`

```
public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('x_customer_category');
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }
```

And I add the column via observer to the view

```
/**
     * Adds column to admin customers grid
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     *
     * @return Mscg_TemplateOverwrite_Model_Customer_Observer
     */
    public function addCustomerGroupToGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if (!isset($block)) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/customer_grid') {
            /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid */
            $block->addColumnAfter('x_customer_category', array(
                'header' => 'x_customer_category',
                'type'   => 'text',
                'index'  => 'x_customer_category',
            ), 'email');
        }
    }
```

However, since this is a option-wise attribute I only get the id of the selected value for the customer but I do want the textvalue, not the entity value of given attribut.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your column type from `text` to `options` and add an `options` element that contains your values in this format  `key => value`.
Something like this:

```
$block->addColumnAfter('x_customer_category', array(
            'header' => 'x_customer_category',
            'type'   => 'options',
            'index'  => 'x_customer_category',
            'options' => array(
                    'id1' => 'label 1',
                    'id2' => 'label 2',
                ),
        ), 'email');
```

If the possible values are dynamic you should first build an array with all the values.  You should know a way to retrieve all the possible values and just assign the array you get to the `options` element.
If your attribute is a standard select attribute you can build it like this:

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'x_customer_category');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
$values = array();
foreach ($options as $option){
    $values[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
```

Then add your column like this:

```
 $block->addColumnAfter('x_customer_category', array(
            'header' => 'x_customer_category',
            'type'   => 'options',
            'index'  => 'x_customer_category',
            'options' => $values,
        ), 'email');
```